# Getting error with build --prod

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

Getting error when build with --prod

project run successfully when i am building without --prod

> ng build && node server.js

```
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 5.83 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 643 kB {vendor} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 204 kB {inline} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.bundle.js, scripts.bundle.js.map (scripts) 755 kB {inline} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 314 kB {inline} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 3.53 MB [initial] [rendered]
API running on localhost:3000
```

but when i run with --prod, i get following errors

> ng build --prod && node server.js

```
chunk {0} styles.650105909265b10581f3.bundle.css (styles) 214 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {1} polyfills.3bc34265385d52184eab.bundle.js (polyfills) 86 bytes {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} main.e402deade8b026b7d50e.bundle.js (main) 84 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} inline.38c436511d2cbf092b64.bundle.js (inline) 1.45 kB [entry] [rendered]

ERROR in ng:///C:/Users/USER/Documents/built-x-web/src/app/views/dashboard/dashboard.component.html (116,33): Operator '>' cannot b
e applied to types 'boolean' and 'number'.
ERROR in ng:///C:/Users/USER/Documents/built-x-web/src/app/views/dashboard/profile.component.html (334,52): Operator '>' cannot be
applied to types 'boolean' and 'number'.
ERROR in C:/Users/USER/Documents/built-x-web/src/$$_gendir/app/components/profile.component.ngfactory.ts (1362,43): Property 'quota
tion' does not exist on type 'FormGroup'.
ERROR in ng:///C:/Users/USER/Documents/built-x-web/src/app/views/dashboard/_searchProjectFilter.component.html (517,1): Operator '>
' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and 'number'.
ERROR in ng:///C:/Users/USER/Documents/built-x-web/src/app/views/dashboard/_searchContactFilter.component.html (95,17): Operator '>
' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and 'number'.
ERROR in ng:///C:/Users/USER/Documents/built-x-web/src/app/views/dashboard/projectDetails.component.html (437,33): Operator '>' can
not be applied to types 'boolean' and 'number'.
ERROR in ng:///C:/Users/USER/Documents/built-x-web/src/app/views/admin/reports.component.html (24,21): Operator '>' cannot be appli
ed to types 'boolean' and 'number'.
ERROR in ng:///C:/Users/USER/Documents/built-x-web/src/app/views/admin/projects.component.html (23,21): Operator '>' cannot be appl
ied to types 'boolean' and 'number'.
ERROR in ng:///C:/Users/USER/Documents/built-x-web/src/app/views/admin/projectView.component.html (593,33): Operator '>' cannot be
applied to types 'boolean' and 'number'.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! crux-app@0.0.0 buildPro: `ng build --prod && node server.js`

npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the crux-app@0.0.0 buildPro script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-10-27T11_08_40_065Z-debug.log
```

it is like it is assuming angle brackets (>) in HTML files as operator.

> HTML code

```
<tr *ngFor="let point of points">
                                        <!-- <td><a [routerLink]="['/dashboard/project-details/', point.opportunityId.id]"> {{point.opportunityId.name}}</a></td> -->

                                            <td class="text-center">

                                                    <span *ngIf="point.points>0; else elseBlock">+{{point.points}}</span>
                                                    <ng-template #elseBlock>
                                                            <span >{{point.points}}</span>
                                                    </ng-template>


                                            </td>


                                        <td>{{point.title}}</td>
           </tr>
```

The error is in the line which i have already commented. however if i comment this whole code block then the error is shifted to another line.
------------------------------------------------------------------------[code and error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31SjH.png)

Comment: You should add the HTML part that causes the error, otherwise its hard to tell what is wrong.

Comment: hi @MartinAdámek i have added the HTMl code.

Comment: Are you really sure that commented line is causing the first error? Have you checked the position (line 116, column 33)?

Comment: Also could you provide us with value of `points` and its type interface. The error looks like you have something wrong in its interface

Comment: @MartinAdámek i have included the screenshot of code and error.